# In views, what is the difference between Normal menu entry, Menu tab and Default menu tab

Tags: views, routes

When adding a menu item in views I see three selections that are ambiguius

Normal menu entry

Menu tab

Default menu tab

What is the difference and when would I use each?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They correspond to the `type` parameter of items returned from [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

- Normal menu entry = [MENU_NORMAL_ITEM](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_NORMAL_ITEM/7)

  > Menu type -- A "normal" menu item that's shown in menu and breadcrumbs.
  >
  > Normal menu items show up in the menu tree and can be moved/hidden by the administrator. Use this for most menu items. It is the default value if no menu item type is specified.
- Menu tab = [MENU_LOCAL_TASK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_TASK/7)

  > Menu type -- A task specific to the parent item, usually rendered as a tab.
  >   Local tasks are menu items that describe actions to be performed on their parent item. An example is the path "node/52/edit", which performs the "edit" task on "node/52".
- Default menu tab = [MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK/7)

  > Menu type -- The "default" local task, which is initially active.
  >
  > Every set of local tasks should provide one "default" task, that links to the same path as its parent when clicked.

The best example I can think of are node pages. When you visit a node page, the 'View' tab is provided by a menu item of type `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` (see `$items['node/%node/view']` in [`node_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_menu/7)).

It doesn't have a path as such (it inherits from the parent menu item), it's only purpose it to allow the node page to have a tab amongst the groups of 'real' tabs, which are defined with `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`.

Comment: Thanks @Clive. The last two are still ambiguous to me. Do you think you could add an example of each to define when I would use one over the other when creating the page for my view?

Comment: I've had a go, hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Sorry it's still not clicking for me. When would "I" use them when making a view?

Comment: Say you wanted to add a view that has a nid as a contextual filter, and you want to have a tab for it on node pages...you would set the path as `node/%node/mypath` and choose "Menu tab". The "Default menu tab" comes into it when you're setting the default for a group of tabs, as in the node page example. `node/[nid]/view` and `node/[nid]` resolve to the same page - the only purpose of the former is to make sure the tab is visible when you visit the latter. Any clearer? It's quite tricky to explain

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Clive. I appreciate it. I think I got it now. I'll give it some time to sink in. :)

Comment: sorry to come back to this one @Clive but it is still not sinking in. How about an example that I am now running into now. I have created a view page and it is just a table list of users and I have created a second page (in the same view) that show the same user on a map. If I wanted to see the two tabs together on either page that allowed the user to flip back and forth between the two, which menu type would I choose for the primary list page and what menu type would I select for the map page?